# Comunicação assíncrona bidirecional em camadas

Tags: c#, mvc, assincronismo

Tenho sistema em Asp.Net MVC (.Net 4.5) dividido em camadas:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Dito isto, vamos ao problema...

Estou tentando criar uma tela para enviar emails de forma assíncrona (3 emails ao mesmo tempo, por exemplo), mas existirá um botão para cancelar os envios, o que me força a informar ao cliente em tempo real, quais emails já foram enviados.

Veja o fluxo abaixo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Neste momento, caso o usuário clique no botão cancelar, os emails em processo devem ser abortados e o último nem inicia.

Respeitando a arquitetura em camadas, eu gostaria de tratar de todas as regras de negócio para o envio dos emails na camada própria para isso. Mas não consegui ainda encontrar uma solução onde eu possa enviar uma lista de objetos (emails) da *View Layer* para a *Business Layer*, criando lá um processo assíncrono que envie de volta para a *View Layer* o resultado do envio de cada email (um por um de forma assíncrona), e que em qualquer momento possibilite a interrupção de todo o processo.

Seria esse o fluxo:

É feito o envio de todos os emails para a camada de negócios:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

A camada de negócios inicia um processo assíncrono para enviar os emails, e a medida que completa o envio de cada email, responde para a camada de visualização o resultado:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

A qualquer momento, o cliente pode cancelar o envio, então a camada de visualização envia uma solicitação de cancelamento para todas as tarefas que ainda estão sendo executadas:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

> **1.** É possível enviar dados em direção contrária (da *Business Layer* para 
>   a *View Layer*) a partir de uma única chamada?
>
> **2.** Devo criar algum tipo de Thread para controlar o envio de cada email?
>
> **3.** É possível interromper uma tarefa que está sendo executada em uma camada inferior?

Comment: Não sei se voto na pergunta, porque ela está um pouco vaga, talvez até ampla ou não clara, mas excelente forma de apresentar.

Comment: Obrigado @bigown , realmente está parecendo um pouco ampla demais, por não se tratar de um problema específico como se propõe aqui no stackoverflow. Estou com dificuldades de sintetizar isso para se encaixar bem, talvez fosse algo para a comunidade [softwareengineering](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/), mas como não temos nada do tipo em português ainda, tive que pedir socorro aqui, rsrsrs...

Comment: O problema não é de foco, e não sabermos bem o que deseja. Aqui é o SEpt.

Comment: Fiz uma edição tentando melhorar um pouco, o que acha agora?

Comment: a melhor opição seria retonar tasks, e primeira camada que fez a requisição, passar um cancelation token para as demais, até a camada que cria as threads de envio, assim é possível cancelar as threads a partir da primeira camada

Answer (score 0):

Eu faria `ViewLayer` trabalhar com javascript (AJAX) chamando `async` a sua BLL (businessLayer) assim seria bem fácil parar a execução do processo.

O Comportamento do $`Ajax` já é async por natureza.
Assim eu poderia chamar uma $Ajax => Start e depois um Stop.
Dentro do Ajax. eu iria recebendo os dados e exibindo para o cliente quais já enviaram.

Answer (score 0):

Voce pode resolver o problema com 3 chamadas sempre originadas do Front End.

1. Chama o seu controller passando lista de emails e qualquer outra informação que seja necessária para o envio. Se o retorno do seu backend for OK/Accepted (STATUS 200/202), você retorna do backend um identificador único para esse processo de envio (PID).
2. Para cancelar o envio crie um novo end point no backend que o Front end no clique do botao possa chamar e cancelar com base no PID.
3. Uma vez que o envio foi iniciado e o Javascript do front-end tem o PID. Voce cria um procedimento de polling (consultas sequenciais) consultando o backend de tempos em tempos verificando estado atual (enviando %, enviado, cancelado) dos itens (emails) do seu pedido. No conteudo desse retorno coloque o que seja necessaria para mostrar no front end se sucesso ou cancelado.

Outra possível implementação que pode ser realizada nesse contexto é a utilização de WebSockets, WebRTC ou SignalR. Basicamente nessas implementações o frontend mantém uma conexão HTTP aberta com o backend recebendo e enviando eventos de/para o servidor pra atualizar seu status de envio em tempo real.

Answer (score 0):

Utilize um sistema de filas, tipo o RabbitMQ, ou o Kafka, ou qualquer outro da tua preferência.

O Business Layer vai publicar na fila todas as informações necessárias pra enviar os e-mails. Cada mensagem na fila é um e-mail que será enviado, então no teu exemplo seriam 7 mensagens publicadas. Também vai inserir no banco de dados uma entidade pra cada e-mail com o status *pendente*.

A fila terá N consumidores conectados a ela (sendo N a quantidade que você quiser) enviando os e-mails e atualizando o status das suas respectivas entidades conforme o resultado do envio (*sucesso* ou *erro*).

Se o usuário clicar no botão de cancelar, limpe a fila. A forma como essa limpeza vai acontecer depende da tecnologia que você escolheu. Uma opção, por exemplo, é ativar um consumidor que faz um fetch de todas as mensagens pendentes e atualiza os status delas pra *cancelado*.

A tela, por sua vez, faz um pooling nesse banco de dados pra consultar os status das mensagens em tempo real. Caso a estratégia de pooling te pareça muito rudimentar, pode utilizar um websocket.

(Dica: Este cenário é muito bacana pra um banco de dados NoSQL, tipo o DynamoDB da AWS ou o CosmosDB da Azure.)

Answer (score -1):

A camada de apresentação (*View layer*) deve funcionar como orquestradora.
Basta criar um *Background Service* de tarefas nesta camada, o qual, irá executar rotinas de envio de email (o serviço de envio deverá estar na *Service Layer*) e sensibilizará a página html utilizando *SignalR*.

O projeto ficará divido da seguinte forma:

- **View Layer – Controller e Views**:
  Aqui iremos adicionar os emails a serem enviados no background service de envio de emails. O background service irá orquestrar os envios e acionará o hub do SignalR, onde a página html estará conectada a este hub e será sensibilizada com status do envio. A pagina html terá rotinas ajax para chamadas de end-point(Send e Cancel) e métodos DOM para databiding.
- **Bussines Layer** – Regras de negócio da aplicação:
  Models e regras de negócio
- **Data Layer** – Repositórios de persistência de dados:
  Repositórios
- **Service Layer** – Serviços externos à arquitetura:
  Serviço de envio de email (*EmailService* – *Adapter* – *Provider*)

Baixe o projeto no meu github: https://github.com/JohnSalazar/background-emailservice-dotnet-mvc.git

Comment: Sua resposta pode ser melhorada adicionando informações fundamentais. Basta [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, como citações ou documentação para que outras pessoas possam confirmar que sua resposta está correta. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).